# Accessing properties in class

Tags: apex

I have the following class with a property called sorToUpdate. I want to access this property to see if a specific Id is in the property. Do I need a specific decorator to do so? I only ask that because I visited the following Link -https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm and it seems like in order to make my properties accessible I have to put a get or set method or declare it public:

Here is my class

```
public with sharing class DynamicSObjectUpdater {

    Map<SObjectType, Map<Id, sObject>> sorToUpdate = new Map<SObjectType, Map<Id, sObject >>();


public SObject getSObject(ID sObjectID)
{
    SObjectType sot = sObjectID.getSobjectType();

    if(!sorToUpdate.containsKey(sot))
    {
        sorToUpdate.put(sot, new Map<Id, SObject>());
    }

    SObject targetSObject = sorToUpdate.get(sot).get(sObjectID);

    if(targetSObject == null)
    {
        targetSObject = sot.newSobject(sObjectID);

        sorToUpdate.get(sot).put(sObjectID, targetSObject);
    }
    return targetSObject;
}

public SObject getUpdateSObject(ID sObjectID, Map<String, Object> values)
{
    SObjectType sot = sObjectID.getSobjectType();

    if(!sorToUpdate.containsKey(sot))
    {
        sorToUpdate.put(sot, new Map<Id, SObject>());
    }

    SObject targetSObject = sorToUpdate.get(sot).get(sObjectID);

    if(targetSObject == null)
    {
        targetSObject = sot.newSobject(sObjectID);

        sorToUpdate.get(sot).put(sObjectID, targetSObject);
    }

    for (String field : values.keySet()) 
    {
        targetSObject.put(field, values.get(field));
    }

    return targetSObject;
}


public void updateSObjects()
{

    List<SObject> sObjectsToUpdate = new List<SObject>();
    if(sorToUpdate.size() > 0)
    {
        for(SObjectType sorType: sorToUpdate.keySet())
        {
            sObjectsToUpdate.addAll( sorToUpdate.get(sorType).values() );
        }
    }
    if(sObjectsToUpdate.size()>0) update sObjectsToUpdate;
}
```

}

I instantiate an object in code like this:

```
    DynamicSObjectUpdater sObjectUpdater = new DynamicSObjectUpdater();
```

And I Want to grab the property sorToUpdate

```
sObjectUpdater.sorToUpdate
```

Comment: You need to specify `public` in front of that variable

Comment: @BryanAnderson What about the Get and Set decorators?

Comment: Unless you want to do something specific when setting or getting a variable, then you don't need to do that. You could have your variable marked as private and then have public `get` and `set` methods to access your variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code with my comment above, note the `public` access modifier to your instance variable `sorToUpdate`:

```
public with sharing class DynamicSObjectUpdater {

    public Map<SObjectType, Map<Id, sObject>> sorToUpdate = new Map<SObjectType, Map<Id, sObject >>();


public SObject getSObject(ID sObjectID)
{
    SObjectType sot = sObjectID.getSobjectType();

    if(!sorToUpdate.containsKey(sot))
    {
        sorToUpdate.put(sot, new Map<Id, SObject>());
    }

    SObject targetSObject = sorToUpdate.get(sot).get(sObjectID);

    if(targetSObject == null)
    {
        targetSObject = sot.newSobject(sObjectID);

        sorToUpdate.get(sot).put(sObjectID, targetSObject);
    }
    return targetSObject;
}

public SObject getUpdateSObject(ID sObjectID, Map<String, Object> values)
{
    SObjectType sot = sObjectID.getSobjectType();

    if(!sorToUpdate.containsKey(sot))
    {
        sorToUpdate.put(sot, new Map<Id, SObject>());
    }

    SObject targetSObject = sorToUpdate.get(sot).get(sObjectID);

    if(targetSObject == null)
    {
        targetSObject = sot.newSobject(sObjectID);

        sorToUpdate.get(sot).put(sObjectID, targetSObject);
    }

    for (String field : values.keySet()) 
    {
        targetSObject.put(field, values.get(field));
    }

    return targetSObject;
}


public void updateSObjects()
{

    List<SObject> sObjectsToUpdate = new List<SObject>();
    if(sorToUpdate.size() > 0)
    {
        for(SObjectType sorType: sorToUpdate.keySet())
        {
            sObjectsToUpdate.addAll( sorToUpdate.get(sorType).values() );
        }
    }
    if(sObjectsToUpdate.size()>0) update sObjectsToUpdate;
}
```